# How can I build and install yum such that it runs exclusively out of a user-owned directory?

Tags: yum, make

I've been searching for one day and I found nothing solid.

All the [instructions](http://yum.baseurl.org/) I've been reading on how to install `yum`, assume I have access to folder `/etc/` so that I can set the file `/etc/yum.conf`. Nonetheless I'm on a shared server and I just have access to my home `~` folder.

Is there a way stil to install `yum`?

I cloned it

```
git clone git://yum.baseurl.org/yum.git
```

and I tried

```
make install DESTDIR="/home4/jfolpf/mydir"
```

with no success

everytime I try to run it, I get

```
CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `yum` is a tool used to install system-wide software packages.  If you do not have access to `sudo` or privileges to write to `/etc`, then `yum` is probably not the tool you're looking for to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: What are you going to do with `yum` once you have installed it? I'm betting there's a simpler way to accomplish your ultimate goal.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, several packages and SW I try to use on the server refer to `yum` as a command for installation.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, the question is that several SW I try to use on the server refer on the instructions to `yum` as a command for installation.

Comment: The odds that those packages will be installable in such a restricted environment would appear to be tiny; they probably assume that system-wide files and directories can be touched. You'd probably be better off focusing on *how to install the software in question in the environment in question* rather than focusing on *how to install yum in the environment in question*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, I will try then as you say. What I'm doing now is using `npm` to install some bin packages ready to run, such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpegtran-bin).

Comment: What software are you trying to install exactly, and why not using root?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I have no access to root! I'm on a shared server. For example [`gcc`](https://crybit.com/how-to-install-gcc-gnu-c-c-compiler-unixlinux/)

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira As DopeGhoti says, yum is intended as a system wide tool. Why the link?